# NodeJS async issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that checks a list of codes if the exist in a database and save them in an array in case they exist :

```
function checkStopsInRoute(stops, callback) {
    var already_in_route_stops = [];
    for (var prop in stops) {
        if (stops.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            var code = stops[prop]["cmp_code"];
            var query_check_stop = "SELECT code FROM stops WHERE code = '" + code + "' AND date = '" + todayDate('/') + "'";
            handle_database(query_check_stop, true, function (response) {
                if (!isEmpty(response)) {
                    console.log("response "+response);
                    already_in_route_stops.push(code);    
                }
            });
        }
    }
    console.log(already_in_route_stops);
    callback(already_in_route_stops);
}
```

This function is called in my app.js like :

```
app.post('/add_companies_to_route', function (req, res) {
var stops = req.body;
        checkStopsInRoute(stops, function(response){
            if (!isEmpty(response)) {
                res.send(prepareResponse("KO", "The stops with the following codes (" + response + ") are already in the route for the current day! Please remove them from the selection", "Error", false));    
            }else{

            }
        });
});
```

Sounds like the for loop in "checkStopsInRoute" function does not wait until the stops are checked and the array "already_in_route_stops" filled because I get in the console:

```
[]
response [object Object]
response [object Object]
response [object Object]
```

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: `checkStopsInRoute` should call `callback` from **inside** the last `handle_database` callback. This is markedly easier with promises, but in your case a counter will do it.

Comment: I am trying to collect all codes that exist so making the callback inside the handle_database will send each code at a time, am I correct?

Comment: No. Read the comment again: *"...from the **last** `handle_database` callback...a counter wll do it..."*

Comment: Sorry I don't see how, could you suggest a code to add please?